# Extension Method in .net 2.0 in VS2008

Tags: c#, .net

```
  public static class Helper
  {
    public static float ToFloat(this string input)
    {
      float result;
      return float.TryParse(input, out result) ? result : 0;
    }
  }
```

I have  added the following at top:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public ExtensionAttribute()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But still I get Type expected error on "this" in Helper class. What's the problem ?

Comment: @James, to define an extension method, sure you can. In fact, you must. But not as early as 2.0. :)

Comment: @James `this` in the way he's using it is normal for extension methods

Comment: see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163317.aspx#S7

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich: I just looked at my extension methods, and you are correct.

Comment: @bzlm: So was I wrong in general, but right with regards to 2.0?

Comment: I erased the evidence of my stupid comment, so I don't know what you are all talking about :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird, the following compiles and runs fine when targeting .NET 2.0:

```
using System;

namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public ExtensionAttribute()
        {

        }
    }
}

public static class Helper
{
    public static float ToFloat(this string input)
    {
        float result;
        return float.TryParse(input, out result) ? result : 0;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string foo = "123";
        Console.WriteLine(foo.ToFloat());
    }
}
```

Comment: I can do this in a new console app but not in my .net 2.0 website for weird reasons. Need to look into it.

Comment: @Learner I think I nailed why this doesn't work in websites. Please check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

The reason that it does work in a command line application is because msbuild knows that the 2.0 .NET CLR can handle extension methods (as they are just static methods with some syntactic sugar).

When compiling a project, msbuild checks the .csproj file for how to compile, what to target etc.

But when compiling a website, there is no .csproj file so msbuild cannot check how to compile. What happens now is that `csc`, the command line compiler, is launched with parameters of how to compile.  So when compiling a .Net 2.0 website, it chooses the 2.0 compiler. But the 2.0 compiler does not know anything about how to compile the extension methods, thus the errors.

You can also notice that if you set the build options under advanced for a regular project to use ISO-2, it will warn you that you cannot use extension methods. But the 2.0 compiler doesn't even recognize the extension methods so it just tells you that you cannot use `this`

**Original post:**

I think there is something else wrong in your code, this compiles just fine in .net 2.0:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string test = "0.0";
            float f = test.ToFloat();
        }

    }
    public static class Helper
    {
        public static float ToFloat(this string input)
        {
            float result;
            return float.TryParse(input, out result) ? result : 0;
        }
    }
}
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public ExtensionAttribute()
        {

        }
    }
}
```